# Compiling and Running CGAL Triangulation Demo

Tags: c++, g++, cgal

I am trying to use the CGAL library to display a 2D Delaunay triangulation, like in the example [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/Triangulation_2_2draw_triangulation_2_8cpp-example.html)

My code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_2.h>
#include <CGAL/draw_triangulation_2.h>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<K> Triangulation;
typedef Triangulation::Point Point;

int main(void){
    Point a(1,1), b(2,1), c(2,2), d(1,2);

    Triangulation T;
    T.insert(a);
    T.insert(b);
    T.insert(c);
    T.insert(d);

    CGAL::draw(T);

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile this code with `g++ -o cgalTest.exe cgalTest.cpp -lCGAL -lgmp` the program compiles successfully, but on runtime I get `Impossible to draw because CGAL_USE_BASIC_VIEWER is not defined`

By searching on Google, I found someone that suggested using `g++ -o cgalTest.exe cgalTest.cpp -lCGAL -lgmp -DCGAL_USE_BASIC_VIEWER` which produces the following error on compile time: `/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:30:10: fatal error: QApplication: No such file or directory #include <QApplication>`

I am using ubuntu 19.04, so I installed CGAl using `sudo apt-get install libcgal-dev` and `sudo apt-get install libcgal-qt5-dev`

I tried to install `sudo apt-get install libqt5svg5-dev libqt5opengl5-dev` as well to solve the error, but to no avail.

Do I need to install additional libraries? Maybe the compilation must be done differently?

Thank you

Comment: Manu qt5 libraries are required: Core, Gui, Help, OpenGL, Script, ScriptTools, Svg, Widgets, qcollectiongenerator (with sqlite driver plugin) and Xml. cf. the installation manual https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/installation.html#title25. You also need to link with CGAL_Qt5

Comment: I checked and I already had `libqt5core5a libqt5gui5 libqt5help5 libqt5script5 libqt5scrpttools5 libqt5xml5` and `libqt5widgets5` installed. I also tried linking CGAL_Qt5 but the error persists.

Comment: What version of CGAL are you using ? The graphical examples are relatively recent (4.13 IIRC). 
Also, you should use cmake and not do all by yourself. It will make it easier to gather all the dependencies, and will warn you if you are missing any.

Comment: I should be using version 4.14. Not 100% sure, since I installed cgal using `sudo apt-get install libcgal-dev libcgal-qt5-dev`. Is there any way I can confirm the version? You suggested using cmake. How would you go about using cmake to compile the above project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, for anyone facing the same problem, here is how I solved it:

First, I used the `locate QApplication` command to find the location of the `QApplication` header file on my system. Be sure to run `sudo updatedb` before using `locate`. If `locate` doesn't find the location of `QApplication` then you are missing qt libraries. Try `sudo apt-get install qt5-default` and the other libraries I mentioned in my question, run `sudo updatedb` and try `locate QApplication` again.

When you find the path to `QApplication` just use the `-I` option to instruct the compiler to use it. Here is an example `g++ -o delaunayTest delaunayTest.cpp -lCGAL -lgmp -lCGAL_Qt5 -DCGAL_USE_BASIC_VIEWER -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/` (because in my case, `QApplication` was inside the directory `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/`)

Trying to compile with this, you will probably get another header file error. Repeat the same process using `locate` until you get no more header file errors.

At that point, you will likely encounter an `undefined reference to symbol` error.

To solve this, use `locate` again to find the location of the file that caused the error (for example `libQt5OpenGL.so.5`) and add the path to the compilation command as is (for example `g++ -o delaunayTest delaunayTest.cpp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5OpenGL.so.5`) along with all the previous options.

You will probably get several `undefined reference to symbol` errors as well. Just keep using the same method until you don't get any.

At this point the program should compile properly and run properly.

Note that if you have multiple versions of qt installed, then the above might not work properly (If for example you have software that uses qt like MATLAB or anaconda installed in your system. You will know because `locate` will produce many paths for each file on the steps above). In such a case, I suggest building a Virtual Machine, downloading the CGAL libraries and `qt5-default` and following the above steps there, since it is very likely this won't work in a system with multiple qt installations.

Comment: This is one main reason to use cmake: simplify the compilation and the link by searching automatically your libraries, and setting the correct flags. You can for example copy the CMakeLists.txt of the examples of Triangulation_2 package; and modify it to compile your program. Then you just have to run cmake. See https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/wiki/How-to-use-CGAL-with-CMake-or-your-own-build-system.

Answer (score 0):

Another option (maybe the easiest), using CMake, is to generate the file using the builtin script:

1. From the source file directory, run `cgal_create_CMakeLists -c Qt5`
2. Edit the generated `CMakeLists.txt` adding the line `add_definitions(-DCGAL_USE_BASIC_VIEWER)`

My generated and edited `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
# Created by the script cgal_create_CMakeLists
# This is the CMake script for compiling a set of CGAL applications.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1...3.15)

project( tmp_cgal )

# CGAL and its components
find_package( CGAL QUIET COMPONENTS Qt5 )

if ( NOT CGAL_FOUND )

  message(STATUS "This project requires the CGAL library, and will not be compiled.")
  return()  

endif()

add_definitions(-DCGAL_USE_BASIC_VIEWER)  # <==== I've added this


# Boost and its components
find_package( Boost REQUIRED )

if ( NOT Boost_FOUND )

  message(STATUS "This project requires the Boost library, and will not be compiled.")

  return()  

endif()

# include for local directory

# include for local package


# Creating entries for all C++ files with "main" routine
# ##########################################################


create_single_source_cgal_program( "b.cpp" )
```

3. Create a `build` directory: `mkdir build`
4. Change directory: `cd build`
5. Generate the build files: `cmake ..`
6. Build: `make`
7. Run the binary file. For me it's `./b` because my source file was `b.cpp`

**Environment:**

These instructions should work for an Ubuntu 20.04.1 (or similar) with the packages `libcgal-dev`, `libcgal-qt5-dev` and `qtbase5-dev` installed (and, of course, `cmake`, `make` and `g++`).

**Main references:**

[doc1](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/devman_create_and_use_a_cmakelist.html) and [doc2](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/devman_create_cgal_CMakeLists.html)